# How to save a CSV from Google Cloud storage into Salesforce Record

Tags: api, google, cloud

Im trying to download a CSV file from google cloud storage and use that same file to be uploaded to the salesforce bulk api, or can it be done in one go - Meaning can I take the CSV file with out downloading it and pass it to the Bulk API?

Answer (score 0):

You can send it to the Bulk API without downloading to your local machine, but you will run a process somewhere that creates the Bulk Job and then posts the contents of the CSV to the Bulk API.

You could use a Google Cloud Function, for example, to do this automatically when a file is created in Cloud Storage.